# PostgreSQL: count rows where condition on start date and end date fits in generated time series

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, count, window-functions

I have data organised like this

```
CREATE TABLE sandbox.tab_1 (id serial, started timestamp, ended timestamp);
INSERT INTO sandbox.tab_1 (id, started, ended) VALUES
    (1, '2020-01-03'::timestamp, NULL),
    (2, '2020-01-05'::timestamp, '2020-01-06'),
    (3, '2020-01-07'::timestamp,  NULL),
    (4, '2020-01-08'::timestamp,  NULL);
```

[image]

I need to count the number of rows where `started >=` and `ended <` than a generated time series that goes from `min(started) to max(started)`. This would give me for each day the stock of started and not ended ids at a given time. The result would be something like this:

[image]

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `LEFT JOIN` the table to the series of timestamps on the start being less then or equal to the timestamp and the end being greater than the timestamp or being `NULL`. Then `GROUP BY` the timestamps and take the `count()`.

```
SELECT gs.ts,
       count(t1.started)
       FROM generate_series('2020-01-03'::timestamp, '2020-01-08'::timestamp, '1 day'::interval) gs (ts)
            LEFT JOIN tab_1 t1
                      ON t1.started <= gs.ts
                         AND (t1.ended IS NULL
                               OR t1.ended > gs.ts)
       GROUP BY gs.ts
       ORDER BY gs.ts;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=9ac949b773360d295b0a832589c0bf75)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option with `generate_series()` and `union all`:

```
select ts, sum(sum(cnt)) over(order by ts) stock
from (
    select generate_series(min(started), max(started), interval '1' day) ts, 0 cnt from tab_1
    union all select started, 1 from tab_1
    union all select ended, -1 from tab_1 where ended is not null

) t
group by ts
order by ts
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddlde](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=65bd2f04f9311a5c942854d06ef9e500)**:

```
ts                  | stock
:------------------ | ----:
2020-01-03 00:00:00 |     1
2020-01-04 00:00:00 |     1
2020-01-05 00:00:00 |     2
2020-01-06 00:00:00 |     1
2020-01-07 00:00:00 |     2
2020-01-08 00:00:00 |     3
```